# Why does ActiveSheet fail

Tags: vba, excel

```
 WB.Sheets(2).Activate
        WB.Sheets(2).Select

         With WKS
            .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(ClientRows, SavedColumn - 1)).Locked = False
            .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(ClientRows, SavedColumn - 1)).FormulaHidden = False
        End With

        With WKS
            .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(ClientRows, 1)).Locked = False
            .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(ClientRows, 1)).FormulaHidden = False
        End With

        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
```

I am looping through a data table and producing multiple Excel worksheets. The attached code works perfectly the first time but the fails with "Object Variable or With Block variable not set". Can anyone help.  Thanks

Comment: Show us how wks is declared and set.

Comment: yeah... where did you declare that wks is your worksheet? is wks even declared? If no you should declare it as worksheet and then "WKS = WB.sheets(2)" you don't have to select it to run a code on it. Avoid selection if possible...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestActivesheet()
    Dim WB As Workbook 'Declare de vars
    Dim WKS As Worksheet

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook 'Or any other workbook || set the var
    WB.Sheets(2).Activate
    WB.Sheets(2).Select

    Set WKS = WB.Sheets(2) 'Again set the var

    With WKS
        .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(ClientRows, SavedColumn - 1)).Locked = False
        .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(ClientRows, SavedColumn - 1)).FormulaHidden = False
    End With

    With WKS
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(ClientRows, 1)).Locked = False
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(ClientRows, 1)).FormulaHidden = False
    End With

    'ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    WKS.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    'ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    WKS.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub
```

Always in the top of every module, is a good practice to use this `Option Explicit`, this way when you use a variable, the compiler ask you to declare it, and avoid this errors.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Also, whilst rewriting the OP's code why not combine the with statements and declare `WKS` next to `WB` then just use `.Activate` and `.select` in the with block. Otherwise this is just inefficient code

Comment: I put comments in my answer, adding the missing part, to explain what is needed. I don't merge the `with` because is not part of the question, and try to let the code as the user does. My ansewer acomplish what the user ask. But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I had to delete line 'Set WB= This workbook 'or any other' workbook as WKS was declared earlier in code.  But it WORKS !!